# AngularJS, Module object and form name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I having trouble to understand some weird problem, I will explain as sort as i can:

For example i got this form:

```
<form method="post" action="index.htm" name="chat" novalidate>
        <label ng-show="chat.message.$error.pattern || chat.message.$error.required" for="message">Some error message</label>
        <textarea ng-required="true" type="text" maxlength="200" id="message" name="message" ng-pattern="patterns.chatMessage" ng-model="chat.message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="send" ng-disabled="chat.$invalid">
</form>
```

Please note(because i didn't included all the code) that `ng-pattern="patterns.chatMessage"` **patterns is a $rootScope property.**

So when the page load i was expecting `chat.message.$error.pattern` to be **false**, But apparently unless i will set `ng-model="some other object like client.message"` or set `ng-model="some other object property like chat.comment"` When the page load `chat.message.$error.pattern` **will be true**, So basically if the model **object.property** is the same as the **formName.textareaName** i got this wierd problem.

**In sort** what is happen is that `chat.message.$error.pattern` is set to true from the moment the page load, If anyone can please explain what is the problem here i will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You cannot use the same scope variable in form's `name` tag and in your `ng-model`.

When you use a form tag in angular, and that tag has a name attribute (e.g. `chat`), the Angular will create an instance of ngFormController on current scope and will assign that instance to a variable as specified in `name` attribute (in this case `chat`).

If you use this very same scope variable `chat` to *host* your `ng-model` than your ngFormController (defined on `$scope.chat`) will become overwritten by your model and it will produce erratic results.

So, to fix things, you need to rename your form:

```html
<form method="post" action="index.htm" name="chatForm" novalidate>
  <label ng-show="chatForm.message.$error.pattern || chatForm.message.$error.required" for="message">Some error message</label>
  <textarea ng-required="true" type="text" maxlength="200" id="message" name="message" ng-pattern="patterns.chatMessage" ng-model="chat.message"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="send" ng-disabled="chatForm.$invalid">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Stewie, I understand now, Can you give me a link so i can read more about ngFormController.

Comment: When in doubt look at the docs: **[`form` directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form)** and **[FormController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form.FormController)**.